# puppeteer web page async code not executed

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, puppeteer

If I 'goto' a web page that contains async code, it is not executed and I don't understand why. Can anyone please help?

Node:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto('http://127.0.0.1:8080/?code=ABC123&id=1', {
    waitUntil: 'networkidle0',
  });
  await page.screenshot({ path: 'example.png' });

  await browser.close();
})();
```

web page:

```
onmount = () => {
    const params = new URLSearchParams(document.location.search);
    const code = params.get('code');
    // above lines are executed     
   
    // the code below is never executed
    // search is an async function (not shown for brevity)
    search(code).then(result => document.getElementById('title').textContent = result.title);   
};
```

Comment: if you go to your app manually is it working?

Comment: By "not executed" you mean the screenshot and the closing of the browser happens earlier than the title textContent update?

Comment: @vinicious
The web page code works as expected in the browser

Comment: @theDavidBarton I am unsure if the async code is being executed at all. If it is, it is not being awaited by Chromium / puppeteer

Comment: Having reread @theDavidBarton’s question and my response, it makes more sense that the async code is being executed but is not being awaited in Chromium. It is executed and awaited in a a browser, so I don’t understand why it isn’t in Chromium?

Comment: As you've found it was network related then the answer is there. You may use the `'--ignore-certificate-errors'` Chromium launch flag https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/. If something else would have caused the issue you could make use of `page.waitForFunction(fn)` to await a slower async function to be finished on your page.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`page.waitForFunction`](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/api.md#pagewaitforfunctionpagefunction-options-args) to listen to the expected result of the original function. Like this, you can make sure the next step (`page.screenshot`) will happen only after the `onmount` promise is resolved in the app.
For this purpose, you could declare the value of the `code=` URL parameter on the top so you could compare its value later on passing it to the `waitForFunction` method as an argument.

```js
await page.waitForFunction(codeValue => document.querySelector('#title').textContent == codeValue, {}, codeValue);
```

Example:

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  const codeValue = 'ABC123';
  await page.goto(`http://127.0.0.1:8080/?code=${codeValue}&id=1`, {
    waitUntil: 'networkidle0',
  });

  await page.waitForFunction(codeValue => document.querySelector('#title').textContent == codeValue, {}, codeValue);
  await page.screenshot({ path: 'example.png' });

  await browser.close();
})();
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to respond to this question. The problem was related to an api call that threw an exception and prevented the async code from resolving. I will close this question. Apologies for wasting anyone’s time

Comment: No such thing as wasted time when it comes to solving general problems  I think you can leave the question open as it can get some general answers later on (just like my answer). You may not accept them - as your solution was a bit specific to your site/environment - others will still find the question and the received answers useful.